# transfer of customizations between different versions in Dynamics Crm

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I need to transfer customization from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 to Microsoft Dynamics 2016, is that even possible if no, is there a workaround solution to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Just try to import your solution. When Dynamics CRM 2016 imports your solution without issues, you are done.
2. Upgrade a development instance of your Dynamics CRM 2015 deployment to 2016 and export the customizations. Then import the customizations in a 2016 organization.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. When you export the solution, if it asks about the version just choose the biggest value (as you are exporting to CRM 2016).